# ppc32 and ppc64 function stack calculation

Tags: embedded, powerpc

I am studying the ppc32 and ppc64 architecture to implement a new backend for my compiler, but I am in doubt about the prolog of a function, I have read several IBM documents about PowerPC, but I have read little information about the stack. of a program, and how exactly it works.
So to try to understand better, I used godbolt.org to check how the functions are compiled and noticed the following:

A function with 4 parameters of type int, the following code is generate for the prolog:

```
test1(int, int, int, int):
        stwu 1,-32(1)
        stw 31,28(1)
        mr 31,1
        stw 3,8(31)
        stw 4,12(31)
        stw 5,16(31)
        stw 6,20(31)
```

A function with 5 parameters of type int, the following code is used:

```
test2(int, int, int, int, int):
        stwu 1,-48(1)
        stw 31,44(1)
        mr 31,1
        stw 3,8(31)
        stw 4,12(31)
        stw 5,16(31)
        stw 6,20(31)
        stw 7,24(31)
```

A function with 10 parameters of type int uses the following code:

```
test4(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int):
        stwu 1,-48(1)
        stw 31,44(1)
        mr 31,1
        stw 3,8(31)
        stw 4,12(31)
        stw 5,16(31)
        stw 6,20(31)
        stw 7,24(31)
        stw 8,28(31)
        stw 9,32(31)
        stw 10,36(31)
```

I noticed that for the 4- and 5-parameter function, the calculation of the stack offset has changed in the following instructions.

```
    ; 4 parameters
    stwu 1,-32(1)
    stw 31,28(1)

    ; 5 parameters
    stwu 1,-48(1)
    stw 31,44(1)
```

But in the 10-parameter function, the offset remained the same as the 5-parameter one and only 8 'stw' instructions were used to load the parameters, the remaining parameters were loaded later using the 'lwz' instruction

Why does it happen ? I think it's something on the stack, but what?

PS.: The assembly code I showed in this question was generated by GCC 4.8.5 PowerPC

Answer (score 0):

You mention that:

> only 8 'stw' instructions were used to load the parameters

- but this isn't code to load the parameters. The parameters are already in registers `r3`-`r10`, as that's how they're passed to the function, according to the ELF ABI.

Instead, those `stw` instructions are storing the function arguments to the stack. It's unclear why the compiler is copying the arguments to the stack without having the function code available, but assuming that your functions are simple, my guess is that you have optimisation disabled, and so it's saving everything to the stack frame.

The reason that there's no difference in the prologue between the 8-argument and 10-argument versions is that only the first 8 arguments are passed via registers. Any further arguments are passed on the caller's stack, and loaded via the `lwz` instruction.

You should read up on the [ELF ABI specification](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/elf/elfspec_ppc.pdf) for ppc, which defines the function calling sequence (section 3-14), amongst other things. While you didn't specify which ABI spec you're compiling against, there shouldn't be a whole lot of variation from the ELF spec in this area.